# Como saltar una columna en un datagrid para imprimir la siguiente?

Tags: c#

Debo imprimir unos documentos, pero cuando llega a un documento que no existe se para la imprecion necesito poder que si al momento de imprimir no lo encuentre salte al siguiente campo y continue imprimiendo los demas

```
public class imprimirmanifiesto
        {
            public void imprimir(string dobleslash)
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "C:\\Users\\bodega\\Documents\\Manifiestos\\" + dobleslash + ".pdf",
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    Verb = "printto",
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    //Arguments = printer,
                };
                p.Start();
            }
        }
```

Boton

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            r = new imprimirmanifiesto();
            int pos = 0;
            bool a = true;
            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (!row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("-1"))
                        r.imprimir(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception q)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Verifique número de importación y seleccione un tipo");
            }
        }
```

Comment: como iteras entre los documentos? no sera que se para porque obtienes un excetion que no estas controlando con un try..catch?

Comment: Listo, actualice la pregunta

Comment: Cómo determinas, dentro del `dataGridView`, cuando existe un documento? Pudieras validar esa condición con un `if`... de esa manera, no saltaría un error, evitas entrar en el `catch` y el ciclo continuaría.

Comment: Como podría validar la existencia con el if?, pasa que si no existe solo se para la impresión y salta el catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No uses un `try/catch`, solo deben usarse para excepciones que no se puedan prever. En tu caso es muy sencillo modificar tu método `Imprimir` para que compruebe si existe el archivo antes de hacer nada y lanzar una excepción:

```
public class imprimirmanifiesto
{
    public void imprimir(string dobleslash)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        string fichero= "C:\\Users\\bodega\\Documents\\Manifiestos\\" + dobleslash + ".pdf";
        if (File.Exists(fichero)
        {
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = fichero,
                UseShellExecute = true,
                Verb = "printto",
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
               //Arguments = printer,
            };
            p.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Como ves, antes de ejecutar el proceso, usamos [`File.Exists`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Exists_System_String_) para comprobar si el fichero existe. Si no existe, no lo lanza, no hay excepción y simplemente se continuará con el siguiente.